# Swf file on iOS

Tags: html, flash

I have a flash file of a room tour that needs to go on the website I'm just wondering how is it possible to load it on iOS? I know iOS doesn't support flash but is there any other way of loading it on a page?

```
<embed src="swf/roomtour.swf" width="100%" height="650" allowFullScreen="true">
```

Link of the room:
[Room Tour Click Here](http://www.limewebsitedesign.com/oldcockinn/rooms.php)

Edit:
or a way to condition this so let is, if the website is being viewed on iOS devices it will hide the flash and say IOS doesn't support the room tour.

Comment: have you ever tried Adobe air ?? adobe Air has IOS export option

Comment: Nope, the file was sent to us by our client as .swf is there a way to reopen it on Adobe air  then export it again? Or shall I just ask them to do it?

Comment: If it has been written by AS3 and you have source FLA file you just need to export it as an IOS app. but if you don't have source file you should create a new project and load it into that ( if its AS3 )